# Searching for matches between sublists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cryptography, python-cryptography

For my final year cryptography module, we learned Shank's "Baby-Step, Giant-Step" algorithm for solving the discrete logarithm problem in modular arithmetic.

Now, in Python, I have coded an algorithm (my exam has been and gone so this isn't to cheat) which appends values required to a list in sublist pairs.
I.e., `list = [[a,b],[c,d],[e,f],[g,a]]`      *Note: I repeated the a value as it's what I am trying to work out.*

I have used DataFrame to print out my list pairwise, however, I need to find any matches between the zeroth pair value of one pair and the first pair value of another pair (i.e. between the left value in one pair and the right value in another pair). In the case of the list above, the first pair's first value matches the last pair's last value.

Is there any way of doing this? I have attempted with some while loops and such, and tried to incorporate them into the end of the code that I have already written, but to no avail.

Many thanks!

Comment: I think you will have to use `for`-loop to compare every two pairs.

Comment: Could you give us an example of the output you are looking for please?